# Fetch user model data and update another model in django

Tags: python, django

I have user model using AbstractBaseUser class. I am registering user using email, username and password.
User class:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Creates a customized database table for user
    """
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email',]

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
```

I want to extend this model to another model called Employee. For extending user model to employee model I have used django signal class.
Employee class:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    """
    Create employee attributes
    """
    employee_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    e_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Employee.objects.create(employee_user=instance)
        instance.Employee.save()
```

In this model there is also a field named email. I have to keep this field because I am using this model to create a form for Employee creation. But the problem is, User model's email field is conflicting with employee email field. I have to keep both the email fields.

Can I update the employee email field with user email field?? If yes, then what should be the query???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `Employee.objects.create(employee_user=instance, email=instance.email)`, but you should evaluate if you need to repeat the data in two tables. You can always access `employee.employee_user.email` whenever you have an Employee instance.

Comment: Yes I can have the access. But I need to create a form using Employee model's field. If I do not give any email field, then how can i add an email field to the form?